# finding the most correlated features in a multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, multivariate-analysis, feature-selection

Assume I have a multivariate time series with 4 features where feature 1 is the most important one for me but at the same time I am suspecting maybe there is at least one more feature (another column of data, which is a time series itself) that is correlated to feature one. Is there anyway to identify this column or this feature?

What I am thinking is to find the correlation coefficient between column 1 and column 2 ... column 4 to see which results in a higher correlation and then choose that feature along with feature 1. The main goal is to perform the clustering of time series but I am not sure how many features I should keep. Can anyone help how to find the most relevant feature in clustering given  the main feature is feature 1 but I am not sure how many others to pick,

Comment: The presence of outliers in any of your series will seriously affect your conclusions. The presence of auto-correlation WITHIN any of your series will VERY seriously affect your conclusions

Comment: Why don't you just compute the correlations between all features and check if there is some large value? That is straightforward to do.

Comment: That's why I did. I made series stationary and compute the correlation however I was thinking maybe Pearson correlation is not appropriate on the time series data (since through I made a series stationary but it is possible that residual is not normally distributed)

Comment: Depends on your data. Some series may, others may not. You can also try Spearman, obviously.